# Flutter - TextFormField - Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints (NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint)

Tags: ios, flutter, ipad, textformfield

With `Flutter Channel stable, 2.0.1`, on iPad phyisical device `iOS 14.4` I have the following console message everytime I tap onto any `TextFormField`.

```dart
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281871540 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109a86990.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185d950 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109b2ddf0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109a86990.bottom - 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185d770 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109b2ddf0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109a86990 )>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185d950 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109b2ddf0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109a86990.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281870e10 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x11c9411b0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2818705f0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c5a3b0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x11c9411b0.bottom - 6   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281871130 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c5a3b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x11c9411b0 )>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2818705f0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c5a3b0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x11c9411b0.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281873ca0 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109ca0d90.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281871040 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca0f60]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109ca0d90 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2818714a0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca0f60.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109ca0d90.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2818714a0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca0f60.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109ca0d90.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x2818702d0 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x126929f40.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185f9d0 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x12692af20]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x126929f40 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185f700 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x12692af20.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x126929f40.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28185f700 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x12692af20.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x126929f40.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281851590 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c45d70.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850c30 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c56fb0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109c45d70 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850cd0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c56fb0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c45d70.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850cd0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c56fb0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c45d70.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281851a40 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c8f2a0.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850f00 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c567b0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109c8f2a0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850fa0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c567b0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c8f2a0.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281850fa0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c567b0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c8f2a0.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x281852710 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3c760.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281851e00 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c3cde0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3c760 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281851ea0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c3cde0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3c760.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281851ea0 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109c3cde0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3c760.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28185c1e0 h=--& v=--& _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3cf60.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2818520d0 V:|-(6)-[_UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca5eb0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3cf60 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281852170 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca5eb0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3cf60.bottom - 6   (active)>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x281852170 _UIUCBKBSelectionBackground:0x109ca5eb0.bottom == _UIButtonBarButton:0x109c3cf60.bottom - 6   (active)>


Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

The onTap on the Textfield just gives the focus to the field - the keyboard appears - but doesn't change anything on the view.

I read that for some people this message can be ignored but for some, the app update has been delcined by Apple.

How can we please fix this constraints issue ?

Comment: I also have same error after updating to flutter 2 stable

Comment: I am getting the same issue on the simulators when the onscreen keyboard is shown and on some devices.

Comment: Same here, anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a bug when using key property in the Form() widget. `GlobalKey<FormState>()`

It could also be your Container/Widget clashing with the keyboard. IOS breaks constraints of screen objects if it causes unstable behaviour.

Try removing your Container (height and width) restraints. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's a Flutter and/or [internal Apple Bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532009/layoutconstraints-unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints) (in my opinion)...it seems to come from the auto-correct options on the keyboard.  Set autocorrect: false, and in most cases you'll avoid the error, however it's not complete.

If you move backwards up a form, tapping in a previous form field, it seems to still trigger.

It doesn't seem to affect user performance, but still best to be avoided.